# ASP.NET ListBox converts ListItem from text, value to text, text

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, listboxitem

I have a problem with the ListBox control in asp.net. I use the following code:

```
List<ListItem> users = new List<ListItem>();
foreach (DataRow dr in dtUsers.Rows)
{
     users.Add(new ListItem(dr["name"].ToString(), dr["userID"].ToString()));
}
lb_users.DataSource = users;
lb_users.DataBind();
```

users consists of the following:

```
ListItem("Hans", "1")
ListItem("Janus", "2")
ListItem("Michael", "3")
```

However when writing out the listitems, bound to the ListBox (lb_users), I get the following:

```
ListItem("Hans", "Hans")
ListItem("Janus", "Janus")
ListItem("Michael", "Michael")
```

I use the following ListBox code:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lb_users" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Can anybody explain why this is or how to fix it?

Thanks,

/Hans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the data text and value fields, e.g:

```
lbl_users.DataSource = users;
lbl_users.DataValueField = "userID";
lbl_users.DataTextField = "name";
lbl_users.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `ListItem` manually like this -

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dtUsers.Rows)
{
    lb_users.Items.Add(new ListItem(dr["name"].ToString(), dr["userID"].ToString())));    
}
```

Or You can just bind straight from `datatable`.

```
lb_users.DataSource = dtUsers;
lb_users.DataValueField = "userID";
lb_users.DataTextField = "name";
lb_users.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually because you are binding to listitem you need to specify properties of ListItem object which are Text and Value so the code should look like:

```
lbl_users.DataSource = users;
lbl_users.DataValueField = "Value";
lbl_users.DataTextField = "Text";
lbl_users.DataBind();
```